# can to print pdf using predefined print framework?

Tags: android-print-manager

How to **print PDF** using predefined **PDF framework** in android ?

How does `Print-Spooler Api` used to print PDF files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
val printManager = this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as PrintManager
            val jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document"
            try{
                printManager.print(jobName, pda, null)
            }
            catch(ex:RuntimeException)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Can't print pdf file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

PrintDocumentAdapter.kt

```
  var pda: PrintDocumentAdapter = object : PrintDocumentAdapter() {
    
            override fun onWrite(
                    pages: Array<PageRange>,
                    destination: ParcelFileDescriptor,
                    cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal,
                    callback: WriteResultCallback
            ) {
                var input: InputStream? = null
                var output: OutputStream? = null
                try {
                    input = uri?.let { contentResolver.openInputStream(it) }
    
                    output = FileOutputStream(destination.fileDescriptor)
                    val buf = ByteArray(1024)
                    var bytesRead: Int
                    if (input != null) {
                        while (input.read(buf).also { bytesRead = it } > 0) {
                            output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead)
                        }
                    }
                    callback.onWriteFinished(arrayOf(PageRange.ALL_PAGES))
                } catch (ee: FileNotFoundException) {
                    //Code to Catch FileNotFoundException
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                   //Code to Catch exception
                } finally {
                    try {
                        input!!.close()
                        output!!.close()
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
    
            override fun onLayout(
                    oldAttributes: PrintAttributes,
                    newAttributes: PrintAttributes,
                    cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal,
                    callback: LayoutResultCallback,
                    extras: Bundle
            ) {
                if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled) {
                    callback.onLayoutCancelled()
                    return
                }
                val pdi = PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("Name of file")
                    .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build()
                callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true)
            }
        }
```

Comment: does this code work for docx files?

Comment: No , it work with pdf only

Comment: How to print docx files then